# Como eliminar clases sucesivamente con un botón

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola amigos tengo varios elementos con una misma clase y deseo agregarles o eliminar una nueva clase a todos los elementos de una forma sucesiva  cunado doy *click* es decir uno por uno en un botón los estoy intentando realizar con un `for loop` pero me elimina o agrega las clases cuando doy *click* en un botón.
Muchas gracias y espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver mi duda

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll(".product-DE");
$("#Next").click(function () {
    
    if (li.length > 0) {
        for (let i = ; i < li.length; i++) {
            li[i].classList.remove("is-right-3k");
        
    }
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes una mezcla de jquery con javascript puro ( lo que no está necesariamente mal ) y el for no está bien construído, además para la finalidad que buscas entiendo que no sería necesario:

```js
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {

  const li = document.querySelectorAll(".product-DE.is-right-3k");

  li.length && li[0].classList.remove("is-right-3k");// <-- Siempre el primero


});
```

```css
.is-right-3k {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product-DE is-right-3k">1</li>
  <li class="product-DE is-right-3k">2</li>
  <li class="product-DE is-right-3k">3</li>
</ul>
<button id="next">
click
</button>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ya realice la corrección de mi código pero me sigue pasando lo mismo de que cuando lo aplico con el for se me quitan todos los cambios y quiero que se quiten de una forma sucesiva cada vez que doy click

Comment: @JesusSanchez uno a uno cada vez que se hace click? ahi actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por la ayuda me podrías indicar de cómo puedo mejorar con javaScript

Comment: Aqui en SOes es un buen lugar, hay buenas resuestas a problemas puntuales, Otro lugar muy importante es [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript)  tiene una documentación muy completa de cada cosa de javascrtip [ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)